# Do photons cause gravity or not?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, photons

I have come across a Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity

On gravity and it claims that since mass and energy are related even pure forms of energy have gravitational attraction. I am in 10th so I have no formal knowledge about relativity or electromagnetism but I have been studying about these and have never come across this statement. It's rather peculiar and I don't think it's true. Please confirm if the page is stating the fact or what?